# Exclude .NET Standard/.NET Core projects from NuGet restore step

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a solution that I am trying to move to being built by VSTS.  I have a dotnet restore step before my VS Build Solution step, but my VS Build step is failing.

> [error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(167,5): Error : Assets file 'D:\a\1\s...\...\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.

But I have Restore NuGet Packages checked on the VS Build, and the dotnet restore step should also fix this.

I'm sure I'm missing something silly with this, but what am I missing with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, it was a silly thing.  I needed to add the last project to the dotnet restore step.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: What do you mean by "The Last project"?

Comment: The one project out of the solution that is .NET Framework, not .NET Standard.